# How to create admin->system->configuration menu in Magento 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a module. That need admin configuration. I don't know how to create menu in admin->system->configuration and how to add items to that custom menu....
please help me....

Answer (score 1):

It involves 4 files for adding a new configuration menu for your module. If your module already have a helper class Data.php, then only two xml files are needed. The helper class Data.php can be empty, it just have to be there for loading your new menu configuration in the admin panel.
The most import two xml files are **adminhtml.xml** and **system.xml** files in your module's etc folder.

**A sample adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <helloworld_setting>
                                        <title>Hello World</title>
                                    </helloworld_setting>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**A sample system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <helloworld translate="label" module="helloworld">
            <label>Hello World</label>
            <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
        </helloworld>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <helloworld_setting translate="label" module="helloworld">
            <label>Settings</label>
            <tab>helloworld</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <greeting_settings translate="label">
                    <label>Greeting Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <greeting translate="label,comment">
                            <label>Greeting</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Greeting text.</comment>
                        </greeting>
                    </fields>
                </greeting_settings>
            </groups>
        </helloworld_setting>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**To retrieve the values you set in the configuration menu**

```
//sectionName/groupName/fieldName
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('helloworld_setting/greeting_settings/enabled');
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('helloworld_setting/greeting_settings/greeting');
```

If there is any problems, make sure the cache is cleared after the code changes, and double check there is no typos in the xml files.